# Unknown options fail to pass with new expl3 method

Tags: expl3, key-value, l3keys

Recently I switched my packages to use the new `\ProcessKeyOptions` method for processing package options. However, I just found out that with

```
\keys_define:nn { projlib-theorem }
  {
    ...
    , unknown .code:n = { \PassOptionsToPackage { \CurrentOption } { create-theorem } }
  }
\ProcessKeyOptions [ projlib-theorem ]
```

the unknown package options are not passed to the package `create-theorem`. I'm not sure when did this issue occur, but it seems to work fine when I'm using the `l3keys2e` and `\ProcessKeysOptions` approach a month ago.

Since I'm not familiar with the mechanism here, there might be something that should be changed alongside `\ProcessKeysOptions` that I didn't change (perhaps the usage of `\CurrentOption`?). How should I modify this code to make it work?

Below is a MWE. If the option `originalref` is successfully passed to the package `create-theorem`, one should see the output "Option works".

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[originalref]{testpackage}
\usepackage{create-theorem}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\bool_if:NTF \l__crthm_regionalref_bool
  { Option ~ does ~ not ~ work }
  { Option ~ works }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

where the `testpackage.sty` is:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2022-06-01]
\ProvidesExplPackage
  {testpackage}
  {2022/07/02} {}
  {A package for testing}

\keys_define:nn { testpackage }
  {
    , unknown .code:n = { \PassOptionsToPackage { \CurrentOption } { create-theorem } }
  }
\ProcessKeyOptions [ testpackage ]

\endinput
```

---

**ADD:** If `testpackage.sty` is the following:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2022-06-01]
\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}
\ProvidesExplPackage
  {testpackage}
  {2022/07/02} {}
  {A package for testing}

\keys_define:nn { testpackage }
  {
    , unknown .code:n = { \PassOptionsToPackage { \CurrentOption } { create-theorem } }
  }
\ProcessKeysOptions { testpackage }

\endinput
```

then the unknown option is successfully passed. Also, with `\ProcessKeyOptions [ testpackage ]`, the code for `unknown` does get executed, for example if one changes the code directly to `unknown .code:n = { \PassOptionsToPackage { originalref } { create-theorem } }`, the output shall become "Option works". Thus the problem seems to be with the usage of `\CurrentOption` here -- perhaps its value does not get updated with `\ProcessKeyOptions`.

Comment: I will take a look: it's possible something is not being passed

Comment: @JosephWright Sure, should this be posted at https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues ? Also, can I safely assume that this will be fixed in a later version of latex-base and nothing needs to be done in my packages?

Comment: There's always the option of doing a "if expl3 version < X then apply patch/workaround Y" to be safe (also to support users of older versions)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a bug report that has already been filed on Github now.

Comment: @JosephWright Thank you for the quick action!